# Refusal notice UK standard visitor

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

[image][image]
I had applied for standard visitor visa to see my daughter (British citizen)''s family  including kids (British citizens) and her husband (Indian citizen on ILO) 0n 18/5/2018 and got refusal as above . While i had visited uk in 2008 and returned back in 2 months (different sponsor).I am unable to understand the refusal  noti ce because of folowing reason's :-
1 ECO has claimed to have considerd interview with applicant and sponsor but no interview has been conducted with me and sponsor.
2. Reason of refusal has been left blank for explanation with a dot mark.
 3.name of ECO has not been entered.
4.General refusal wording is written in which reasons are also not entered .These wordings clearly show that reasons must be entered but it is not done.moreover refusal writing guidance also mentions explanation of any refusal to be entered in refusal notice.

In the light of above I want to ask if this refusal notice is justified and do all general refusal wordings  mentioned in refusal notice apply to me or are they general one??
To whom should I write for explanation.?
No such activity was done on my part that such deception charges may apply to me .
Are there chances that appllication and supporting documents  of some other person may have been considered for me .
What should I do .kindly suggest .thanks

Comment: We have, unfortunately, seen this before, where they somehow fail to actually give you a proper refusal notice and just sent you the blank template document instead of an actual decision. As noted in the linked duplicate, the regulations say you're supposed to get a proper decision, so I'd contact them and request one. That won't automatically result in your application being accepted, but at least you'll know why it was refused so you can react accordingly.

Comment: @zach lipton should I assume that decision of refusal is final  now which otherwise may not have been taken based upon fact that no reason for refusal has been documented and now they will manipulate refusal notice as per the decision on asking for proper refusal notice..?

Comment: I don’t believe UKVI would ‘manipulate’ a decision, I would expect that the refusal reason is actually recorded in the UKVI files but wasn’t transferred to the advice letter by mistake. As Zach Lipton states, you need to contact them to get the full details so that you understand the reason and can try to address it in future applications.

Comment: To whom should I contact ??local UK consulate....?? Which section...? ? Can anybody provide contact details for getting proper notice from ukvi...??